# $.each() loop through json not looping

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

i have an ajax call that gets back json i am trying to send the items returned to specific input text id's.

This is the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "php/myfirstfile.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: $("#frameroof").serialize(),
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (json) {
        $.each(json, function () {
            $.each(json, function (key, value) {
                /// do stuff
                $('#' + key ).val(value);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

This is what is returned: `[{"a-frame":"100"}][{"vertical":"350"}]`

it looks im getting 2 arrays when i need one to loop over. Im not sure.

Here is the php

```
if(isset($_POST["cart"])){
    $frameArray = ($_POST["cart"]);

    if(is_array($frameArray)){
        foreach($frameArray as $row){
            $catalogue = $row['catalogue'];
            $certification = $row['certification'];
            $catagory =  $row['catagory'];
            $subcatagory =  $row['subcatagory'];
            $length = $row['length'] ;

            $sql = "SELECT `price` AS  '$subcatagory' FROM `products` WHERE `catalogue_id` = '$catalogue' AND  `certification` = '$certification' AND `catagory` = '$catagory' AND  `sub_catagory` = '$subcatagory' AND `length` = '$length' ";

            $result = $short_connect->query($sql);

            if (($result) && ($result->num_rows > 0)) {
                $results = array();
                //convert query result into an associative array
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $results[] =  $row;
                }

                //dump all data from associative array converted from query result
                echo (json_encode($results,true));

                $result->free();
            }
        }
    }
}

$short_connect->close();
```

Comment: `[{"a-frame":"100"}][{"vertical":"350"}]` as a string is not a valid JSON

Comment: I think you are trying to loop over a string.

Comment: Is it possible to see what some of your PHP looks like?

Comment: That is not valud JSON. Either you're trying to manually output JSON (which you should never do) and are breaking it, or your server code is running twice. Either way, we need to see the server side code.

Comment: here is the php code

Comment: JAAulde thta looks better than the way i do it sorry im a nob

Comment: It's all good--no problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is pretty simple. Inside of your loop you're initializing the results array and you're outputting it. This causes a new results array to be created, serialized to JSON, and outputted for every iteration of the loop. Thus what you're sending the browser is not JSON, but several chunks of JSON all run together.

This is the basic idea of what you need to be doing:

```
<?php
// Initialize the output data
$results = array();

foreach($something as $a_something) {
    $results[] = do_something_to($a_something);
}

//Serialize and send the output data
echo (json_encode($results,true));
```

Rearranging your code with that pattern in mind produces this (which ought to work for you, and will return an empty array to the browser if your `if` conditions aren't met or the query doesn't return anything):

```
<?php

// Initialize the output data
$results = array();

if(isset($_POST["cart"])){
    $frameArray = ($_POST["cart"]);

    if(is_array($frameArray)){
        foreach($frameArray as $row){
            $catalogue = $row['catalogue'];
            $certification = $row['certification'];
            $catagory =  $row['catagory'];
            $subcatagory =  $row['subcatagory'];
            $length = $row['length'] ;

            $sql = "SELECT `price` AS  '$subcatagory' FROM `products` WHERE `catalogue_id` = '$catalogue' AND  `certification` = '$certification' AND `catagory` = '$catagory' AND  `sub_catagory` = '$subcatagory' AND `length` = '$length' ";

            $result = $short_connect->query($sql);

            if (($result) && ($result->num_rows > 0)) {
                //convert query result into an associative array
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    //Add to the output data
                    $results[] =  $row;
                }

                $result->free();
            }
        }
    }
}

$short_connect->close();

//Serialize and send the output data
//dump all data from associative array converted from query result
echo (json_encode($results,true));
```

Comment: your the coding man. i really appreciate that more than you know

Comment: No problem! Keep plugging away and interacting here on SO--you'll keep on gettin' better!